# How to specify this particular header in Postman

Tags: rest, postman, http-headers, base64, postman-collection-runner

Resource URL

```
GET https://<MATD_IP>/php/session.php
```

The following HTTP headers should be specified in the session request:

```
Accept: application/vnd.ve.v1.0+json
Content-Type: application/json
VE-SDK-API: Base64 encoded "user name:password" string
VE-API-Version (Optional)
```

I am confused onto what does it mean by specifying base64 encoded string. I have tried to do it but I am failing at it. Can anybody help me with the exact header parameters by giving an example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this in your `Pre-request Script`:

```
let base64 = Buffer.from("username:password").toString('base64')

pm.request.headers.add({key: "VE-SDK-API", value: base64})
```

This will convert to Base64 and then create the header with the encoded value.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely means that you need to provide a base64 string for that field. Write down the credentials with a **:** in between. Ex:

**cooluser:str0ngP4ssword**

Then you encode this exact string as base64 which would give you:

**Y29vbHVzZXI6c3RyMG5nUEBzc3dvcmQ=**

You can encode via terminal (Linux) `echo "XXX" | base64` or just search for "base64 encode" on the WEB (not really recommended due to security reasons).

You can then use it for the headers:

```
Accept: application/vnd.ve.v1.0+json
Content-Type: application/json
VE-SDK-API: Y29vbHVzZXI6c3RyMG5nUEBzc3dvcmQ=
VE-API-Version 1.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Omit echoing trailing new line using option `-n` (for *not needed*):

```
echo -n "username:password" | base64
```